winCases does not have a type name
Here's the situation:
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::string winCases[8];
  winCases[0] = "00,11,22";
  winCases[1] = "02,11,20";
  winCases[2] = "00,01,02";
}

When I compile this I get the following errors:
thing.cpp:12:3: error: 'winCases' does not name a type
   12 |   winCases[0] = "00,11,22";
      |   ^~~~~~~~
thing.cpp:13:3: error: 'winCases' does not name a type
   13 |   winCases[1] = "02,11,20";
      |   ^~~~~~~~
thing.cpp:14:3: error: 'winCases' does not name a type
   14 |   winCases[2] = "00,01,02";
      |   ^~~~~~~~

Can anybody kindly help me?
what is this part for? ignore this please

Try including the string header

Are you sure that these are the only errors? I expect you missed copying the first error about this line: std::string winCases[8]; because of the missing #include <string> if that is not the case I am not sure this is an accurate [mcve] or at least I am not sure that the shown code causes only the shown errors.

#include <std::string> #include <vector> using std::string; using std::vector; std::vector<std::string> winCases; You need to tell the compiler which string class you are using.  Also, use vector instead of array.
